# Octave call a function as a variable of another function

Tags: octave

I wrote a bisection method in Octave but it can't consume another function..

My bisection method code is like:

```octave
function[x,b] = bisection(f,a,b)

  t = 10e-8

  while abs(b-a) > t;
    c = (a+b)/2;

    if f(a) * f(b) <= 0
       a = a;
       b = c;
    else 
       b = b;
       a = c
    endif
  endwhile

  x = (a+b)/2
endfunction
```

And I already have a file f1.m:

```
function y = f1(x)
  y = x^2 - 4;
endfunction
```

But when I call `[x,v] = bisection[f1,0,5]`, I get:

```
>> [t,v] = bisection(f1,0,5)
   error: 'x' undefined near line 2 column 5
   error: called from
          f1 at line 2 column 3
   error: evaluating argument list element number 1
```

Comment: Where is argument `x` of the function `f1` in your call?

Comment: note that this code is specific to octave btw. matlab will not run this; you might either want to remove the matlab tag or alter the code to make it matlab-compatible

Answer (score 5):

what you want is to pass a pointer to `f1` to your function `bisection` so the right call would be

```
[t,v] = bisection(@f1,0,5)
```

which outputs:

```
t =    1.0000e-07
a =  0.62500
a =  0.93750
a =  1.0938
a =  1.1719
a =  1.2109
a =  1.2305
a =  1.2402
a =  1.2451
a =  1.2476
a =  1.2488
a =  1.2494
a =  1.2497
a =  1.2498
a =  1.2499
a =  1.2500
a =  1.2500
a =  1.2500
a =  1.2500
a =  1.2500
a =  1.2500
a =  1.2500
a =  1.2500
a =  1.2500
a =  1.2500
x =  1.2500
t =  1.2500
v =  1.2500
```

Answer (score 4):

Andy has given you the answer on how to fix this. I would just like to add why you get that error and what it means. Consider the following octave session:

```
octave:1> function Out = g1(x); Out = x+5; end
octave:2> function Out = g2(); Out = 10;end
octave:3> 
octave:3> g2
ans =  10
octave:4> g1
error: 'x' undefined near line 1 column 29
error: called from
    g1 at line 1 column 27
```

I.e., when you write `g1` or `g2` here, this is an *actual function call*. The call to `g2` succeeds because `g2` does not take any arguments; the syntax `g2` is essentially equivalent to `g2()`. However, the call to `g1` fails, because `g1` expects an argument, and we didn't provide one.

Compare with:

```
octave:4> a = @g1;
octave:5> b = @g2;
octave:6> a
a = @g1
octave:7> a(1)
ans =  6
octave:8> b
b = @g2
octave:9> b()
ans =  10
```

where you have created *handles* to these functions, which you can capture into variables, and pass them as arguments into functions. These handles could then be called as `a(5)` or `b()` *inside* the function that received them as arguments, and it would be like calling the original `g1` and `g2` functions.

When you called `bisection(f1,0,5)`, you essentially called `bisection(f1(),0,5)`, i.e. you asked octave to evaluate the function `f1` without passing any arguments, and use the result as the first input argument to the `bisection` function. Since function `f1` is defined to take an input argument and you didn't supply any, octave complains that when it tries to evaluate `y = x^2 - 4;` as per the definition of `f1`, `x` was not passed as an input argument and was therefore undefined.

Therefore, to pass a "function" as an arbitrary argument that can be called *inside* your bisection function, you need to pass a function *handle* instead, which can be created using the `@f1` syntax. Read up on "anonymous functions" on the [octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Function-Handles-Anonymous-Functions-Inline-Functions.html#Function-Handles-Anonymous-Functions-Inline-Functions) (or [matlab](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html)) documentation.